# HttpChannel и проблема CORS, как отдавать нужные заголовки?

Tags: c#, .net, http, vb.net, .net-remoting

Имеется расширение для Google Chrome, которое отправляет по протоколу XML-RPC данные на сервер. Сервер XML-RPC - это десктопное .NET приложение.

Вот код инициализации сервера:

```
    Dim properties As IDictionary = New Hashtable

    properties.Item("name") = "hostChannel"
    properties.Item("port") = 5678

    Dim chnl As New HttpChannel(properties, Nothing, New XmlRpcServerFormatterSinkProvider)

    Try

        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chnl, False)

        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(GetType(StateNameServer), "statename.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton)
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(GetType(CoderServer), "statename.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка")

    End Try
```

При отправке ajax-запроса на этот сервер защита CORS не дает правильно работать и вызывает ошибку в надстройке.

Для того чтобы это работало надо чтобы сервер отдавал правильные заголовки.
А так же на OPTIONS запрос от браузера, отвечал кодом `200 OK`.

Для веб сервера на базе Apache эта проблема устранена созданием `.htaccess` файла в корне домена, со следующим содержимым.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blank.php [QSA,L]
```

Каким образом решить данную проблему для вышеупомянутого `HttpChannel` ?

**UPDATE**
В документации есть пример добавления заголовков через прокси сервер, но как это сделать не понимаю.
http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-3-0-0.html#2.6

Comment: Интересно, может кто еще в третий раз отредактирует мой пост...? А что давайте соревнование устроим кто лучше отредактирует?

Comment: Согласно правилам пользования сайта, ваш пост уже в общественном достоянии, так что можно не заморачиваться )

Comment: Не уверен, что HttpChannel вообще поддерживает пользовательские заголовки...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov В документации есть пример добавления заголовков через прокси сервер, но как это сделать не понимаю. http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-3-0-0.html#2.6

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь э... Это же c++! Какое отношение он имеет к HttpChannel?

Comment: Какой еще C++? Я наверное знаю какую библиотеку я использую и в каком проекте и в на каком языке!!! `using CookComputing.XmlRpc;` Это во вашему C++ ?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь вот этот код - точно из C++: `proxy->SumAndDifference(2, 3);`

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь а вам следовало бы с самого начала указать, что вы используете библиотеку XML-RPC.NET

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь кстати, ни о каком "прокси-сервере" в документации не говорилось, вы ошиблись с переводом. Приведенный вами фрагмент кода - он вообще для клиента, а не для сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека XML-RPC.NET основана на .NET Remoting. Функционал .NET Remoting можно расширять, передавая в конструктор канала объекты под названием [sinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdzwhfy3(v=vs.100).aspx). При помощи таких объектов можно, в том числе, добавить HTTP-заголовки в ответ.

Для создания своего sink на стороне сервера нужно написать классы, реализующие интерфейсы `IServerChannelSink` и `IServerChannelSinkProvider`, затем объединить созданный провайдер в цепочку с провайдером из библиотеки XML-RPC.NET (`XmlRpcServerFormatterSinkProvider`), и передать его в конструктор `HttpChannel`.

Далее приведен пример класса `ExtSink`, который:

- Добавляет в ответ сервера заголовки, переданные как параметр конструктора `headers`.
- Если в запросе используется метод OPTIONS, возвращается ответ `200 OK` с пустым телом (заголовки также добавляются).

Основной код расположен в методе `ProcessMessage`.

```
public class ExtSink : BaseChannelSinkWithProperties, IServerChannelSink
{
    private IServerChannelSink _next;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _headers;

    // headers - набор http-заголовков для добавления в ответ
    public ExtSink(IServerChannelSink next, IDictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        _next = next;
        _headers = headers;
    }

    public void AsyncProcessResponse(IServerResponseChannelSinkStack sinkStack,
        object state, IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders headers, Stream stream)
    {
        sinkStack.AsyncProcessResponse(msg, headers, stream);
    }

    public Stream GetResponseStream(IServerResponseChannelSinkStack sinkStack,
        object state, IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders headers)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public IServerChannelSink NextChannelSink
    {
        get { return _next; }
    }

    public ServerProcessing ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack,
        IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders,
        Stream requestStream, out IMessage responseMsg,
        out ITransportHeaders responseHeaders,
        out Stream responseStream)
    {
        sinkStack.Push(this, null);

        var next = _next;

        var method = (string)requestHeaders["__RequestVerb"];
        if (method.Equals("OPTIONS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            // формальные параметры
            requestMsg = new MethodCall(new Header[0]);
            requestStream = null;

            // обходим выполнение xml-rpc sink (который находится в _next),
            // если используется метод OPTIONS
            next = _next.NextChannelSink;
        }

        var result = next.ProcessMessage(sinkStack, requestMsg,
            requestHeaders, requestStream, out responseMsg,
            out responseHeaders, out responseStream);

        // копируем заголовки в ответ
        if (responseHeaders == null)
            responseHeaders = new TransportHeaders();

        foreach (var header in _headers) {
            responseHeaders[header.Key] = header.Value;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Класс `ExtSinkProvider` - простая фабрика для создания экземпляра `ExtSink`:

```
public class ExtSinkProvider : IServerChannelSinkProvider
{
    private IServerChannelSinkProvider _next;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _headers;

    public ExtSinkProvider(IDictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        _headers = headers;
    }

    public IServerChannelSink CreateSink(IChannelReceiver channel)
    {
        var next = _next.CreateSink(channel);
        return new ExtSink(next, _headers);
    }

    public void GetChannelData(IChannelDataStore channelData)
    {
    }

    public IServerChannelSinkProvider Next
    {
        get { return _next; }
        set { _next = value; }
    }
}
```

Затем объединяем провайдер `HttpHeadersSinkProvider` в цепочку с провайдером `XmlRpcServerFormatterSinkProvider` из библиотеки:

```
var properties = new Hashtable {
    { "name", "hostChannel" },
    { "port", 5678 },
};

// заголовки, которые будут добавлены в ответ
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
    { "Access-Control-Max-Age", "1000" },
    { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding" },
    { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" },
};

// объединяем провайдеры в цепочку
// первым должен быть ExtSinkProvider, чтобы иметь возможность обойти выполнение xml-rpc
var providersChain = new ExtSinkProvider(headers);
providersChain.Next = new XmlRpcServerFormatterSinkProvider();

// цепочку передаем в конструктор канала
var channel = new HttpChannel(properties, null, providersChain);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
    typeof(TestService), "statename.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```